# View pdf in browser but save with wrong file name

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, pdf, adobe-reader

I have a form where when a user presses the download button it a get_file.php script returns the specified php file. In ffx when I disable the adobe plugin, a download box appears with the correct file name. In IE8 I cant disable the adobe plugin for some reason, so it always opens in browser. This works fine, however, in both ffx and IE8, when I press the save button from the adobe toolbar I get the wrong file name. I get get_file.pdf.

I am using adobe reader 8.

These are the headers I'm setting:

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Pragma:");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$pdfFileName");
```

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a bug in the adobe plugin

Answer (score 2):

Setting tha pdf filename is quite complex. It dependeds what are you needs/environment.
Sometime ago I wrote a small doc about the topic.  Hope it could be useful for you.
https://docs.google.com/View?docid=dchmct9k_9dxkdwk

Comment: I think I've tried all of that and still nothing :l thanks though

Comment: @Fabrizio Accatino, you clearly state that IE build from itself the file name when you save it thought Acrobat PDF plugin preview. Still same behavior with IE 11 !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"Content-Disposition: inline;`, try `"Content-Disposition: attachment;`.

Comment: I wan't it to open in the browser using the adobe plugin. Won't this remove that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the filename to end of URL, it works fine for me

ex:

```
get_file.php/Myfilename.pdf
```